# jQuery UI Sortable and Draggable issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a nested Sortable which is not working quite well on it's own, but I've added a Draggable too, which is causing even more problems.

- Sorting items between nested Sortables is almost impossible, try it ;)
- Dragging a Draggable into the inner Sortable also adds a new item to the outer Sortable as well

Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Melvin/PgFR8/)

I guess this is just impossible to achieve with the current version of jQuery UI.

---

Edit: [see comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249283/jquery-ui-sortable-and-draggable-issues#comment-7287998)

Comment: Seemed to work OK for me in Chrome 12 on Windows 7.

Comment: Can't test Chrome 12 since I've got 11, but is also seems to fail in Firefox 4, Opera 11 and Internet Explorer 9, tested on Windows 7

Comment: it is not impossible I have done it but with a little bit of an effort... hold up...

Comment: It doesn't "fail" for me in Firefox 4.0.1 although I agree with your first point moving Item 1 in Container 2 to the end of Container 2 creates a weird effect and it's a nuisance to pin-point the drop point the item.

Comment: I´ve managed to resolve the second issue by only adding a Sortable instance to the outer container and changing the 'items' selector from '> .item' to '.item'.

It is still a bit jumpy but that's probably related to the styling, as I'm not much of a designer, I'll search for a fix and update my post accordingly.

Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Melvin/PgFR8/2/)

Comment: Made it less jumpier by adding a 3px high placeholder [Version 3](http://jsfiddle.net/Melvin/PgFR8/3/), I guess I'm OK now and my issues have been resolved.

Comment: @Melvin: Check out [Google Chrome Canary](http://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs), it's 2 versions ahead of stable but you can have both installed no probs.

Comment: I'm glad it works in 12, but I need it to work in 11 too, as this is going to be a client project, I need it to work in all major browsers. I'll definitely take a look at the Canary release, thanks!

Comment: I tried it with Chrome 17. It is not working. I think it is a JQuery UI bug or design issue that it lack the "greedy" option as droppable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>
       <ul> <li>Item 4</li> </ul>
   </li>
</ul>

$('ul').bind('mouseenter',function (){
   //$(this).parents('ul').sortable('destroy');//this line is optional... :)
   $(this).sortable({'items':'li'});
});
$('ul').bind('mouseleave',function (){
   $(this).sortable('destroy');
});
```

this may not work as I have not tested it but you do get the idea I hope :)

Comment: This makes dragging items from the outer Sortable into the inner Sortable less jumpier but it breaks the ability to move items from the inner Sortable to the outer one, it also breaks the ability to drag new items from the Draggable into a Sortable, but thanks for trying to help me out

Comment: one tip, is that you should use ul,li combination, as its easier to manage, and sortable handles them better :)

Comment: Sorting div elements should not be any problem as it behaves just like a list item if you add "display: list-item;". I can't use the ul > li combination because I need a more complex container where not all items have the same parent, if you know what I mean.

Comment: @melvin Oh yes I know what you mean, then you should use the drag and drop features, where droppable has an `accept` so that can be dropped where ever you wish :) and then `serialise`, with sortable at the end and destroy sortable seemlessly, so you can save the list via ajax :)